# xml to xhtml: empty namespace attribute added (xslt 2.0, saxon9he)

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I am trying to transform xml to xhtml using xslt 2.0.

I am creating separate documents for some elements, like this:

```
<xsl:result-document method="xhtml" href="output/{generate-id()}.html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" encoding="utf-8" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
            </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="{generate-id()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:result-document>
```

I am having trouble with the namespaces, though. Some of the created documents look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="d1e1203">

            <img xmlns="" src="file:/P:/199/199201.tif" alt=""/>

            <h1 xmlns="">gfdg</h1>

            <h1 xmlns="">gfdg</h1>

            <img xmlns="" src="file:/P:/124/124566.tif" alt="gdf"/>
<!-- and so on -->
```

Why is the `xmlns=""` added to some descendants of html?

And if I put it like this:

```
<xsl:result-document method="xhtml" href="output/{generate-id()}.html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" encoding="utf-8" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
        <html>
```

then no empty namespace attributes are added. However, when I transform one of those documents, I get the following error:

```
Warning: SXXP0005: The source document is in namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml, but all the
  template rules match elements in no namespace (Use --suppressXsltNamespaceCheck:on to
  avoid this warning)
```

How do I handle the namespaces correctly?

Comment: You are not providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In general, if you **copy** an element with no namespace, then it will appear the way you show, in order to distinguish it from the default namespace you have established by `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`.

Comment: Well, I'm not really copying anything. I just want to create xhtml documents. And for that, as I understand it, the html-Tag needs to have the xhtml namespace and I need the xhtml Doctype. What is missing from my example code?

Comment: "*What is missing from my example code?*" (a) the input; (b) the context (what does your template match?);  (c) the part/s where you create the  `img` and  `h1` elements (other templates in your stylesheet?). **Please review the link in my first comment.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use different templates that are supposed to create XHTML result elements then you need to move `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` up to the `xsl:stylesheet` (respectively `xsl:transform`) root element of your stylesheet e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">`.

As for writing stylesheets that process (read in) XHTML documents with elements in the XHTML namespace, with XSLT 2.0 the easiest is using `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element, as that way you can write match patterns like `<xsl:template match="p">...</xsl:template>` and XPath expressions like `//table` matching respectively selecting elements in the XHTML namespace, without the XPath/XSLT 1.0 need to bind a prefix to the namespace and use the prefix in all patterns and expressions.

Comment: But that assumes you want all your results to be XHTML.

Comment: Yes, but "I am trying to transform xml to xhtml" sounds like that is the case, if not, a template can do e.g. `<xsl:template match="foo" xmlns=""><bar>...</bar</xsl:template>` to override the namespace declaration.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! I wanted all my results to be xhtml!

Answer (score 1):

If Saxon outputs `<img xmlns=""/>`, that's because your result tree contains an `img` element in no namespace, and some ancestor element is in a namespace such as the XHTML namespace. To avoid the unwanted namespace undeclaration, you need to ensure that the `img` element in the result tree is created in the correct namespace. You haven't shown the code that generated the `img` element, but the most common mistake is to use a literal result element in the stylesheet in the form `<img/>` with no in-scope declaration of a default namespace. The best way of fixing this is often to declare the XHTML namespace on the xsl:stylesheet element, rather than on the instruction that outputs the `html` element.